# Call Apex Rest Services from Community and maintain User Context

Tags: apex, community, apexrest

I have a community setup and an apex rest service. I've enabled the class for the community users profile and the guest user. The profile is api enabled and apex rest enabled. I can call the rest service from the lightning component but it is always called as the guest user. It doesn't maintain the logged in community users context. I don't want to use a username and password Oauth flow. The user has already logged in and I obviously don't want to store users usernames and passwords, and I don't want a named credential because I want the users context not a delegate. I also want to be able to call the service with straight hrefs. The domain is the same and the cookies get passed to the service just fine so it seems odd that the user context doesn't get maintained. Any thoughts on how to make it work?

Comment: Why would you need to expose an apex as web service to be called from a lightning component in community -- any particular reason?

Comment: I'm proxying a web service through it, and the service returns documents that I want users to download. I want to be able to just link to the service with an a tag and have the browser download the document without going through an xhr request since there doesn't seem to be a good way to trigger the file download